# Configure Visual Studio Toolset path in docker container for cmake

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio, cmake, msbuild

I used an example from
[Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/build-tools-container?view=vs-2022#using-the-built-image) to create a build container for C++ app.

It works and i can use vs prompt with working msbuild.exe.

Nevertheless when i try to use cmake to preconfigure my project it throws

> Generator : Visual Studio 17 2022 could not find any instance of Visual
> Studio.

How can i force declare vs toolset install path for it inside container?

Tried to set paths, but nothing changed

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean by 'force declare vs toolset install path', but the doc you linked from microsoft provides a docker file with a line referencing vs_buildtools. This line can be modified to install the components you need.

Here is an example of what I have which is working for a C++ cmake project (conan):

```
    && (call C:\TEMP\Install.cmd vs_buildtools.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache install `
    --installPath "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools" `
    --channelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --installChannelUri C:\TEMP\VisualStudio.chman `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.22621 `
    --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --includeRecommended`
    --remove Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK)
```

Here is a description of the CLI parameters for vs_buildtools: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/use-command-line-parameters-to-install-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Here are some examples of using those parameters: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/command-line-parameter-examples?view=vs-2022

Here is a link with IDs to workloads/components which you can use to build out the components you need: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/workload-component-id-vs-build-tools?view=vs-2022

If you need to discover information about your build tools, you can use vswhere.exe:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe -all -products *
```

Finally, there are some CMake variables mentioned here, which might help: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE.html

In particular:

> If the value of CMAKE_GENERATOR_INSTANCE is not specified explicitly
> by the user or a toolchain file, CMake queries the Visual Studio
> Installer to locate VS instances, chooses one, and sets the variable
> as a cache entry to hold the value persistently. If an environment
> variable of the form VS##0COMNTOOLS, where ## the Visual Studio major
> version number, is set and points to the Common7/Tools directory
> within one of the VS instances, that instance will be used. Otherwise,
> if more than one VS instance is installed we do not define which one
> is chosen by default.